# Turning text in a text file to lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, file-io, dictionary

so for example i had a text file with peoples phone numbers,name,address.
that looked like this with a return at the end of each line

```
555-667282,bill higs,67 hilltop

555-328382,john paul,85 big road

555-457645,zac fry,45 tony's rd

555-457645,kim fry,45 tony's rd
```

and i wanted to put it all in a dictionary and in the dictionary the phone number was the key and there name and address was a list.
so if i wanted to print the dictionary it would look something like this. what would be the code to do this

> {555-667282: ['bill higs','67 hilltop'], 555-328382: ['john paul','85 big road'], 555-457645: ['zac fry','45 tony's rd'],['kim fry','45 tony's rd']}

Answer (score 2):

```
dicto = {}

with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        s_line = line.rstrip().split(',')
        dicto[s_line[0]] = s_line[1:]
```

Edit:

To handle cases where there are multiple entries associated with one phone number:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicto = defaultdict(list)

with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        s_line = line.rstrip().split(',')
        dicto[s_line[0]].append(s_line[1:])
```

Comment: This doesn't properly handle the case where there are two entries with the same phone number.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks for pointing this out. I edited my post to address that point.

Answer (score 1):

This file format is what the `csv` module in the standard library was designed to handle. However you can't have a dictionary laid-out the way you want because a dictionary key can only map to one thing. A simple way to work around that limitation is to map each phone number to a list of lists, as shown in the sample code and output below:

```
import csv

result = {}
with open('numbers.txt', 'rb') as input:
    for phone_number, name, address in csv.reader(input):
        if phone_number in result:
            result[phone_number] += [[name, address]]
        else:
            result[phone_number] = [[name, address]]

print result
```

Output:

```
{'555-328382': [['john paul', '85 big road']], 
 '555-457645': [['zac fry', "45 tony's rd"], ['kim fry', "45 tony's rd"]], 
 '555-667282': [['bill higs', '67 hilltop']]}
```

The code within the inner `for` loop can be simplified by using another standard library class called `defaultdict` which is a subclass of `dict`. They automatically initialize dictionary entries to a specified default value whenever a non-existent one's value is referenced. Here's how one could be applied to this example:

```
import collections
import csv

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('numbers.txt', 'rb') as input:
    for phone_number, name, address in csv.reader(input):
        result[phone_number] += [[name, address]]

print result
```

Output of second version:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
 '555-328382': [['john paul', '85 big road']],
 '555-457645': [['zac fry', "45 tony's rd"], ['kim fry', "45 tony's rd"]],
 '555-667282': [['bill higs', '67 hilltop']]})
```

`defaultdict` objects can otherwise be used just like a regular dictionary by the rest of your code.